# C# paint graphics on the edge of the window

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm developing an application that simulates traffic patterns and represents each vehicle as a colored rectangle.

As the program is running, each Vehicle's **position** is incremented based on     **speed** until it gets too close to the vehicle ahead of it.

```
private void SlowDown(int carBehind, int carAhead, List<Vehicle> vehicles)
{
        vehicles[carBehind].SetActualVelocity(vehicles[carAhead].GetVelocity());
}
```

**Then I increment each Vehicle's position:**

```
private void AdvancePosition(List<Vehicle> vehicles)
    {
        Vehicle tempVehicle;
        double velocity = 0;
        int position = 0;
        int newPosition = 0;
        for(int i = vehicles.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) //starting with forward vehicles first
        {
            tempVehicle = vehicles[i];
            velocity = tempVehicle.GetVelocity() * 1.466667 / 33; //convert mph to fps then allow for 30 frames per second
            position = tempVehicle.GetPosition();
            newPosition = (int)(velocity + position);
            tempVehicle.SetPosition(newPosition);
        }
    }
```

This works great until Vehicles go from off-screen to on-screen *(or position negative to position positive)*. They begin to creep up on each other and eventually overlap even though I set their speeds to be equal.

**Here is my code for painting the graphics**

```
private void paintTraffic(Road road, List<Vehicle> vehicles)
    {

        using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
        {
            Vehicle tempVehicle;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int index = 0;
            int vehicleSize = 0;

            Refresh();
            for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.Count; i++)
            {
                /*
                 * I tried using this condition but I'm still seeing the problem
                 *if(x < vehicleSize)
                 *{
                 *   vehicleSize = x;
                 *}
                 */
                tempVehicle = vehicles[i];
                x = tempVehicle.GetPosition();
                y = tempVehicle.GetLane() * 100;
                vehicleSize = tempVehicle.GetSize();
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(color), x, y, vehicleSize, 20);
            }

        }
    }
```

Each Vehicle is painted as a small rectangle where the Vehicle's position is the front of the Vehicle.

**My question is:** This doesn't seem like a calculation error by the program because the Vehicle's speed is set to that of the Vehicle in front of it.

Does this sound like a Graphics bug or a strange calculation error?

Comment: So far I'm just skimming, but this is either very bad nomenclature or busted logic: `newPosition = (int)(velocity + position);`  You can't add velocity and position; they have different units.

Comment: CreateGraphics is bad, too.  Use the paint event of the container.

Comment: It is just a logical error in your model.  If cars that get into a traffic jam only ever adjust to each other's speed by slowing down then they'll inevitably always come to a dead stop.  You *must* allow them to speed up if there is a gap.

Comment: All of these comments and I will refactor accordingly. However, they won't solve the problem I have and asked about.